# What are the solutions for the inequality $x^2 \geq 60$

Tags: inequality, radicals

I searched it up on wolfram and the result it shows is:
$x \geq 2 \sqrt {15}$ and $x \leq -2 \sqrt {15}$.
What I am doing is:

$x \geq \pm 2\sqrt {15}$

Now, two cases arise,

$x \geq 2\sqrt {15}$ or $x \geq -2\sqrt{15}$

Could someone show me where I am going wrong in my way?

Comment: The analytical step, $~x \geq \pm 2\sqrt{15},~$ is wrong.  Re-read and re-consider the first line of your posted question.

Comment: If $x\geq 60,$ then are you sure that $x \geq \pm 2\sqrt {15}$?

Comment: Given an inequality of the form $x^2 \ge a$, when one takes the square root of both sides, one gets $|x| \ge \sqrt{a}$, which means that either $x \ge \sqrt{a}$ or $x \le -\sqrt{a}$. Note that the negative square root uses $\le$, not $\ge$.

Comment: @user2661923 Could you please tell me why that is wrong? It works in normal algebra.

Comment: Look in your own posting.  On the first line, you have (in effect), with $~0 < A,B~$ that $~A \geq B~$ or $~\color{green}{-A \leq -B}.~$  On your second (wrong) line, you have (in effect) the alternative $~A \geq B~$ or $~\color{red}{-A \geq -B}.$  The $~\color{green}{\text{green}}~$ and $~\color{red}{\text{red}}~$ portions **do not match**.

Comment: Start with a simpler case: Which real numbers $x$ satisfy the inequality $x^2 \ge 9$?

Comment: There is an underlying (unspoken) issue: *why* did you go off the rails?  I think it is because you attempted to use *memorized* formulas instead of attempting to attain a moderately deep *understanding* of the material.  The memorization strategy is a recipe for disaster when studying math.